# How to handle an event in Windows C++

Tags: c++, events

How would I setup a custom event and event handler in Windows C++?

An analog for what I want to accomplish would be something similar to what this is doing in nodejs:

```
//in main execution context:

var app = require('myapp');

app.on('ready', function(){
    //An event handler for the ready event
})

var i = 10;
foo(i);
//... do other stuff 

================================================
//in a different execution context:

app.doStuff();
app.emit("ready");
```

What is the Windows C++ mechanism for setting and event handler and continuing execution?

Comment: You'll need to clarify what exactly you mean by "Windows C++", raw winapi? MFC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handler is an abstract concept that exists somehow is all general purpose programming languages.

C++ is no exception.
For C++ under windows you can define a custom event, a source that will raise this event, and a receiver or an event listener/handler.

Check the sample code here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/event-handling-in-native-cpp

Comment: Huh, alright, I guess I was expecting something built into C++ for custom events. Thanks!

Comment: Check these posts too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711414/what-is-the-proper-way-of-doing-event-handling-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464025/designing-an-event-mechanism-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Here the way you can handle event in C++.

```
            CMyApp::CMyApp()
            {
             m_hThreadEvent = 0;
            }

            // strcuture for send parameter to ThreadProc
            struct sThreadProcParam
            {
               HANDLE m_hEvent; //Handle close the app event.
            }

            UINT CMyApp::InitializeApp()
            {
               sThreadProcParam *param = new sThreadProcParam;
               param->m_hEvent = 0;
               
               m_hThreadEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE , FALSE ,NULL);
               if(!m_hThreadEvent) return 1;
               
               param->m_hEvent = m_hThreadEvent;
               
               HANDLE Hwnd = CreateThread(NULL,0, ThreadProc , param , 0 , NULL)
               if(!Hwnd) return 1;
               
               //Rest of code for initialization
            }   

            CMyApp::OnClose()
            {
                //Signal to Thread function event
                SetEvent(m_hThreadEvent);
                m_hThreadEvent = 0;
                
                //Other code for close handle
            }
```