# Does boost::any need RTTI?

Tags: c++, performance, boost, rtti, boost-any

On the Boost web site I found no information regarding the use or RTTI by boost::any.

I read in a few places that this is a requirement, but then I built a simple test project, and it builds both with and without RTTI.

So, is RTTI, with its performance and memory issues, needed by boost::any and similar classes?

Comment: I've just tried to build a simple program with boost_any, and an executable built with -fno-rtti was actually larger than one built without. I have no idea what it means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since boost 1.57 RTTI is not needed for `boost::any`. Rememeber that all objects used as `boost::any` must by copyable.

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10346

Comment: I must say that if compilers would not just disallow `typeid` with RTTI disabled and allowed its use in non-polymorfic context, it would work without need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @paweldac: OK, that is the reason of the contradicting information I found.