# Checking std::any's type without RTTI

Tags: c++, types, rtti, stdany

I'm using `std::any` with RTTI and exceptions disabled. It works and `std::any_cast<T>()` is able to detect whether the type is correct as explained in [std::any without RTTI, how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51361606/stdany-without-rtti-how-does-it-work). `std::any::type()` is disabled without RTTI though.

I'd like to check whether my `std::any` object contains a value of a given type. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You said that `any_cast`'s detection works even without RTTI. So... just use that to detect what type it is.

Comment: @NicolBolas Exceptions are also disabled, so a bad any_cast will crash the program.

Comment: @user253751: Not if you cast a pointer to an `any` to a `T*`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::any without RTTI, how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51361606/stdany-without-rtti-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cast a pointer to your `any` value and check whether the result is null:

```cpp
#include <any>
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    std::any any = 5;
    
    if( auto x = std::any_cast<double>(&any) ) {
        std::cout << "Double " << *x << std::endl;
    }
    if( auto x = std::any_cast<int>(&any) ) {
        std::cout << "Int " << *x << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```