# C++ std::any function that convert std::any of C char-array to string

Tags: c++, string, c-strings, rtti, stdany

```
#include <iostream>
#include <any>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

string AnyPrint(const std::any &value)
{   
    cout << size_t(&value) << ", " << value.type().name() << " ";
    if (auto x = std::any_cast<int>(&value)) {
        return "int(" + std::to_string(*x) + ")";
    }
    if (auto x = std::any_cast<float>(&value)) {
        return "float(" + std::to_string(*x) + ")";
    }
    if (auto x = std::any_cast<double>(&value)) {
        return "double(" + std::to_string(*x) + ")";
    }
    if (auto x = std::any_cast<string>(&value)) {
        return "string(\"" + (*x) + "\")";
    }
    if (auto x = std::any_cast<char*>(&value)) {
        return string(*x);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    float b = 2;
    double c = 3;
    string d = "4";
    char *e = "555";
    
    cout << AnyPrint(a) << "\n";
    cout << AnyPrint(b) << "\n";
    cout << AnyPrint(c) << "\n";
    cout << AnyPrint(d) << "\n";
    cout << AnyPrint("555") << "\n";
    cout << AnyPrint(e) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to make a function that converts a `std::any` object to string, given that the list of possible types is hard-coded. However, there's a problem when user parse raw string like `AnyPrint("555")`. I use the method from [Checking std::any's type without RTTI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63524970/checking-stdanys-type-without-rtti)

I got the following output when I run the program:

```
140722480985696, i int(1)
140722480985696, f float(2.000000)
140722480985696, d double(3.000000)
140722480985696, NSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE string("4")
140722480985696, PKc string("4")
140722480985696, Pc 555
```

How can I handle a `std::any` of raw string? I don't want to write `AnyPrint("555"s)` unless it's the only way.

Edit: I use this to run the example https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

Comment: I would rather implement this using templates and specializations rather.

Comment: How do you use template on `std::any` though? The input being `std::any` is a requirement, since it's the output from another library

Comment: If you're using `using namespace std;` (which is often adviced against), you should at least use is consistently and have `string AnyPrint(const any &value)`, `if (auto x = any_cast<int>(&value))` etc.

Comment: @hyde I'm aware of this. I just use it in examples to make everything short

Comment: Also, `AnyPrint` is missing return statement in case none of the `if` match. It must always return something.

Comment: (never mind about the if stuff in deleted comment, I re-read the docs...)

Comment: Type of `"555"` is `const char[4]` which might decays to `const char*`. You handle `char*`, not `const char*`.

Comment: if the number of types to be used is fixed you do not need `std::any`. `std::variant` seems more appropriate

Comment: `char *e = "555";` is not allowed since C++11. It must be `const char*`

Comment: I don't quite get what behavior you are *expecting* here, or what you *want* to happen instead of what is actually happening?

Comment: @DevSolar its not explicit in the question, but one line of output is missing due to undefined behavior because `AnyPrint("555")` does not return

Comment: Add `return "Oh dear!";` at the end of `AnyPrint`. (When something can't happen, it usually will.)

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks I already have that, I forgot to copy that part into the question sample code

Comment: where did `140722480985696, PKc string("4")` come from?

Comment: @康桓瑋 `cout << AnyPrint(d) << "\n";`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number. Ok. Then where did `140722480985696, NSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE string("4") `come from?

Comment: @康桓瑋 you can try running code on the link in the post. `140722480985696` is address of `const std::any &value`

Comment: I mean why would the result of `cout << AnyPrint("555") << "\n"` be `140722480985696, PKc string("4")`? Your link doesn't have any code, I'm pretty sure I won't get this result using your code in OP. What do you expect to get? and what do you actually get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type of `"555"` is `const char[4]` which might decays to `const char*`. You handle `char*`, but not `const char*`.

Handling `const char*` fixes your issue:

```
std::string AnyPrint(const std::any &value)
{   
    std::cout << size_t(&value) << ", " << value.type().name() << " ";
    if (auto x = std::any_cast<int>(&value)) {
        return "int(" + std::to_string(*x) + ")";
    }
    if (auto x = std::any_cast<float>(&value)) {
        return "float(" + std::to_string(*x) + ")";
    }
    if (auto x = std::any_cast<double>(&value)) {
        return "double(" + std::to_string(*x) + ")";
    }
    if (auto x = std::any_cast<std::string>(&value)) {
        return "string(\"" + (*x) + "\")";
    }
    if (auto x = std::any_cast<const char*>(&value)) {
        return *x;
    }
    return "other";
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca7edc7f3b62f4cf)

Comment: For good measure, throw in the handling of `char*` too (since the `any_cast<const char*>` won't pick that up).

Comment: Do I have to handle case `const X` for all other types ? What about reference values?

Comment: Here, it is not `const X` vs `X` but pointer so `X* const`/`X*` versus `const X*`.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, string literals like `"555"` are (or decay to) `const char*` pointers. Your `AnyPrint` function doesn't handle such an argument type.

Adding the following block fixes the problem:

```cpp
    if (auto x = std::any_cast<const char*>(&value)) {
        return string(*x);
    }
```

Also, note that the line, `char *e = "555";` is illegal in C++; you need either `const char *e = "555";` or `char e[] = "555";`; using the latter will demonstrate the difference between the `char*` (with `AnyPrint(e)`) and `const char*` (with `AnyPrint("555")`) types in the `std::any_cast<T>` blocks.